# SIGINT signal handler behaviour difference in python 2.7 vs 3.7

Tags: python, signals, sigint

```
import signal

def handler(signum, frame):
    exit(0)

signal.signal(signal.SIGINT, handler)

str = 'abc'*1000000000
print(str)
print("done")
```

the above give code when run with python3.7, stops immediately on pressing ctrl+C , but when run with python2.7 takes multiple key strokes of ctrl+C.

If there is a valid reason for this behaviour please let me know.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there is a valid reason for this behavior. The behavior of `time.sleep` has changed between Python 2.7 and Python 3.7.

From [the Python 2.7 documentation](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/time.html#time.sleep):

> The actual suspension time may be less than that requested because any
> caught signal will terminate the `sleep()` following execution of that
> signal’s catching routine.

From [the Python 3.7 documentation](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/time.html#time.sleep):

> *Changed in version 3.5:* The function now sleeps at least *secs* even if
> the sleep is interrupted by a signal, except if the signal handler
> raises an exception (see **[PEP 475](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0475/)** for the rationale).